# Why can’t Zorn’s lemma be used to show any module has maximal submodule

Tags: modules, ideals, axiom-of-choice, maximal-subgroup

So you can use Zorn’s lemma to show that if $R$ is a ring then $R $ has a maximal left ideal. Show you would let $X$ be the set of all proper left ideals of $R$. Then can show any chain has an upper bound and so Zorn’s lemma shows that $X$ has a maximal element which is the maximal left ideal. I assume this proof is absolutely standard, but why can’t we just replace ideals with left submodules and instead of talking about ideals of $R$ we talk about submodules of $M$, say. What fails in the proof?

Comment: I think the problem is you can't say the upper bound of a chain (i.e. the union of its elements) is not in fact $M$ itself. In the ring-ideal case you have that the union of any increasing chain is still proper because $1$ is not included.

Comment: With proper ideals you can say any ideal doesn’t contain $1$ right and so the upper bound (the union of ideals in the chain) doesn’t contain $1$ either, right. But with submodules as you say the union could be the whole module itself right and so not proper?

Comment: @Ben yes, exactly.